# Android SimpleDateFormat Not Working

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Quick question, `SimpleDateFormat` is not performing as I would expect. I am looking to get a date string that look like `Thursday 29 November 13:43`.

Here is my format:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
_clockDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("cccc dd MMMM kk:mm");  
_clockDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
```

Here is the output:

```
5 29 11 13:43
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `cccc`? I dont know this pattern. go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: From the android documentation `c|stand-alone day of week|(Text/Number)|Tuesday/2`

Comment: @MaximShoustin It is [in the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html): stand-alone day of week. To be honest I'm not sure how it can be used.

Comment: @assylias well but its not refer to `SimpleDateFormat` :)

Comment: Are you sure you want `kk` rather than `HH`? That's pretty unusual.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do want `HH`, thanks sir

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you know that `c` is for?

Comment: @assylias: C is for dayname/daynumber. See the example there, Tuesday/2.

Comment: @assylias: My guess is that it's for when *all* you're displaying. When it's part of a full date/time, I suspect EEEE is the more appropriate format specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the device I am working with doesn't have a default locale when it gets here from the factory. As a workaround I used the `Locale` specific overload for `SimpleDateFormat`:

`_clockDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM HH:mm", Locale.US);`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `c` use `E`:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
SimpleDateFormat _clockDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM kk:mm");  
System.out.println(_clockDateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

output:

> Thursday 29 November 14:05

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

Comment: @BheshGurung: It is pointing to java5 javadoc. I clicked one more time to make sure.

Comment: I still get the numeric values even with `EEEE`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say wrong version (or wrong class). There is no `c` in that list.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: I guess something wrong going on with your code then, I would suggest refresh and see.

Comment: Formatting the `Date` object generated by calling `getTime()` on the default `Calendar` instance I get the numeric values, not the text :(

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: think your _clockDateFormat pointing to wrong formatter. I have exact code and got above output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 _clockDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM kk:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

In my pc I have tried the following

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
    SimpleDateFormat _clockDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy dd MMMM kk:mm");  
    _clockDateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(_clockDateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

if i use 'cccc' in simpledateformat it gives an error!!!

Comment: `yyyy` is the year, not the day of the week.